# Left join with different entities using linq query

Tags: linq

I am using a linq query in that I have two entity models I am unable to use left join I have implemented in this way I am getting null exception

```
var query = from r in ContactsContext.My_schedule_categories.Where(rp => rp.Usr_schedule_owner_usr_id == currentID)    
            join p in profileContext.My_schedule_categories on r.Usr_schedule_category_id equals p.sid into g
            Where(pr => pr.sid == pr.catid)

            from p in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                category = r.Usr_schedule_category,
                caid = r.Usr_schedule_category_id,
                oid = r.Usr_schedule_owner_usr_id,
                sid = p.sid
            }
```

So can you please send me any sample code how can I left join two table with different entity models?

Comment: I've formatted the code, but that `Where()` method seems a bit out of place...does that work?

Comment: i am using asp.net mvc3 4.0 razors

Comment: my problem is not with where condition i need to implement left join with different entities plaese canu provide me any sample code.

Comment: the where canalso be written after the end of query.

Comment: if it's linq to sql it won't work, the system won't know how to build up that question between two different contextt however you can make them both objects in memory by adding .Tolist() and have them in memory, howver not a good idea if the lists contains to many items.

Comment: please can u send example (or) sample code that in which i can implement the query.

Comment: Actually i have two tableA, tableB i have records in tableA.   If i have the same related records in tableB then i shouls display TRUE if records are not inserted in tableB it should display FALSE. so please tell me in which way i can proceed.